# Give a example to show that there not necessarily exist $\{e_j\}$ such that $f_i(e_j)=\delta_{ij}, i,j\geq 1$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, dual-spaces, hamel-basis

> Suppose $X$ is a normed linear space. $\{f_i\}\subset X^*$ are linearly independent. Give a example to show that there not necessarily exist $\{e_j\}$ such that $f_i(e_j)=\delta_{ij}, i,j\geq 1$.

I understand that $X$ may not equal the space spanned by $e_1, e_2, \cdots$ and there are already many posts on MSE discussing about dual basis of infinite dimensional space. But I have not founded the answer of my question. Appreciate any help or hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $C[0,1]$ with the sup norm. Arrange the rational numbers in $[0,1]$ in a sequence  $(r_n)$. Let $f_i(x)=x(r_i)$. Each $f_i$ is a continuous linear functional on $C[0,1]$. Suppose we have $(x_j)$ such that $f_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$. Then $x_j(r_i)=\delta_{ij}$. So $x_j(r)=0$ for all rational numbers $r$ except one. By continuity it follows that $x_j\equiv 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: How to show $\{f_i\}$ are linearly independent please?

Comment: Suppose $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_kf_k=0$. There exists a continuous function $x$ such that $x(r_i)=1$ and $x(r_j)=0$ if $1 \leq j \leq n$ and $j \neq i$. Evaluating at this function $x$ we get $a_i=0$ This is true for each $i$ so $f_i$'s are linearly independent.  @xunitc

Comment: I am not sure I understand that. because $x \in C[0,1]$ and $x(r_i)=1$, so if $t\in(r_i-\delta,r_i+\delta)$, then $|x(t)-x(r_i)|<\epsilon$, let $t$ is a rational then $x(t)=0$, so $|0-1|<\epsilon$, contradiction. what is my wrong?

Comment: @xunitc In proving linear indepedence of $f_i$'s we are onoly interested in a **finite number** of these functions. So we are using only a finite number of rational numbers in the argument. Given rational numvers $r_1,r_2,...,r_n$ is is possibe to find a continuous function $x$ with the properties I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now.